# Send parameter hashtag to another page in php

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with send parameter with value hashtag (#) in a HTTP request.

Example I have matcontents is `#3232`, then i need to sent parameter wtih that value. I've tried doing this:

```
echo "<td width=25% align=left bgcolor=$bgcolor id='title'>&nbsp;<font face='Calibri' size='2'>
              <a href='../report/rptacc_det.php?kode=$brs3[matcontents]&fromd=$fromd2&tod=$tod2&type=$type&fty=$fty&nama=$brs3[itemdesc]' target='_blank'>
              $brs3[matcontents]</a></font></td>";
```

But when i call kode on rptacc_det.php, i got nothing or blank. How do i send value like "#3232" to another page??

Comment: Pls i know my sentence kinda worst but, pls answer my question!!!

Comment: var urlSplit = document.URL.split("#");
    location.href = "http://www.example.org" + "/" + urlSplit[1];

Comment: @VforVendetta u mean i need use javascript???

Comment: yes you can try other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything after a `#` is not sent to the server in a request as it's interpreted as an anchor location on the page.

It *is* possible to send them, but you need to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) them.

```
$kode = "this is a #test";

// Does not work:
// In the following, $_GET['parameter'] will be "this is a ";
// link will be '?kode=this is a #test'
echo '<a href=../report/rptacc_det.php?kode' . $kode . '>Click</a>'; 

// Works:
// In the following, $_GET['parameter'] will contain the content you need
// link will be '?kode=this%20is%20a%20%23test'
echo '<a href=../report/rptacc_det.php?kode' . urlencode($kode) . '>Click</a>';
```

To get the value back in  `rptacc_det.php`, you can use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
$kode = urldecode($_GET['kode']);
```

You should do this to all variables which you are including in a URL.